# How to fix " (1/1) ErrorException compact(): Undefined variable: categories in AdminPostsController.php line 23 '"

Tags: laravel

I want to create a post but I cannot because it shows me the **Undefined variable** error for the `compact` function,
can someone help me?

Below are the samples from files:

**AdminPostsController.php**

```php
public function index(){
    $posts = Post::paginate(5);

    return view('admin.posts.index', compact('posts','categories'));
}
```

**admin/posts/index.blade.php**

```html
@extends('layouts.admin')


@section('content')
        <h1>Posts page</h1>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Photo ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Body</th>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>Updated</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @if($posts)
                @foreach($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$post->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->user->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->category_id ? $post->category->name : 'No category'}}</td>

                    <td><img height="50" src="{{$post->photo ? $post->photo->file : 'http://placehold.it/400x400'}}"></td>
                    <td><a href="{{route('admin.posts.edit', $post->id)}}">{{$post->title}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{str_limit($post->body,10)}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->updated_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{route('home.post', $post->id)}}">View post</a> </td>
                    <td><a href="{{route('admin.comments.show', $post->id)}}">View comments</a></td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            @endif
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-5">
                {{$posts->render()}}
                {{--pagination--}}
            </div>
        </div>


@stop
```

Comment: Where in your controller do you define `$categories`?

Comment: public function create(){

        $categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id')->all();

        return view('admin.posts.create', compact('categories'));

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `$categories` variable is defined in the index function inside your controller.

```
// AdminPostsController.php
public function index(){

    $posts = Post::paginate(5);
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('admin.posts.index', compact('posts','categories'));
}
```

Comment: yes, i think this helped me but now I have another problem "(2/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/master/resources/views/admin/posts/index.blade.php)"

Comment: This should probably get it's own post, but it sounds like you are using `->name` on a variable/object that doesn't have that property. You may have to format either your blade file or the controller to provide those details.

Comment: Thank you!!
This help me